# status 400 returned from upload of jaxb bean with nested array

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I'm developing a restful webservice using java and glassfish.  The webservice consumes JSON.  I've created a JAXB bean with a few simple fields along with a nested array of other jaxb beans.  I've included the relevant code below.

When I populate my bean with **only** the simple fields, the web service accepts the incoming bean, processes it and returns appropriately.

when I add the nested array of sub beans, I get a status 400 back from the server...  I'm concerned that the manner in which i annotate the getter method might be affecting the overall bean as it's passed to the server?

I've also added the code for my tester i'm using to push the beans to the server

here is the method signature of the webservice in question:

```
@POST
@Path( "test1" )
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response createRecord( JAXB_ExampleBean track )
```

here is the top level bean:

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "example" )
@XmlType( propOrder = { "id", "idCreator", "title", "revList" } )
public class JAXB_ExampleBean
{
private long id = 0;
private long idCreator;
private String title;
private ArrayList<JAXB_ExampleRevBean> revList;

@XmlElementWrapper( name = "exampleList" )
@XmlElement( name = "exampleRevision" )
public ArrayList<JAXB_ExampleRevBean> getRevList()
{
    return revList;
}

    // other getters/setters omitted for brevity no additional annotations on them

}
```

Here is the nested bean:

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "exampleRevision" )
@XmlType( propOrder = { "id", "idExample", "idAuthor", "revOrder" } )
public class JAXB_ExampleRevBean
{
private long id = 0;
private long idExample;
private long idAuthor;
private int revOrder;

    // getters/setters omitted for brevity no additional annotations on them
}
```

Here is the tester code:

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource( "http://example.com/resources/meta/test1" );

JAXB_ExampleBean beanToUpload = buildExampleBeanToSend();

ClientResponse response = webResource.type( "application/json" ).post( ClientResponse.class, beanToUpload );
if( response.getStatus() != 201 )
   throw new RuntimeException( "Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus() );
```

Comment: What are you using as your JSON binding provider?  If you're not sure which application server are you using?

Comment: ok... I'm so close now! I removed the two annotations on the getter method for the list and I converted ArrayList to just List.  I'm able to push the bean to the server, but now when the list contains only 1 object it fails... 2 or more entries in the list and   it works... please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try with array [] or List instead of Arraylist. Most of the serialization/deserialization frameworks do not handle concrete collection classes.